# How to limit concurrent matrix/multi-configuration builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a multi-configuration job that uses a large amount of VMs for testing.

The Axis are something like:
30 VM slaves, 5 configurations, 5 different configurations

I would *not* like to run these sequentially, as the jobs would take forever. However, the default number of simultaneous runs is using up enough resources that I am getting random failures and disconnects.

Is there are way to specify the maximum number of simultaneous tests within this single running job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use a matrix job to trigger the builds of a separate job doing the real build. Then 
you can use the [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) to limit the number of parallel executions of that job you start by the matrix.

Comment: Does this work for you? Maybe it's my conbined use of the 'Groovy Label Assignment plugin' that breaks things for me, but I've tried this: 1 master, 2 slaves (4 executors each), project with 1 axis with 5 values, and a 'Groovy script to restrict where this project can be run' so the flyweight is on master and the others on the slaves, throttling on this project alone and maximum total and node 1, throttle master and configuration builds on. Result: 1 slave gets 4 builds running at the same time. Am I missing something?

Comment: It turns out the combination of matrix job and throttling does not work when using 'Throttle this project alone', but does work when using a throttle category.

Comment: @Legolas, I thried both, and it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

For multi project configuration

1. First you need to create a throttle category. In this case, the name is `qa-aut` and I limiting the number of execution to 2 for concurrent builds and concurrent builds per node. The node will have 4 executors available.
   [image]
2. In your job configuration, make sure you don't run the multi-project sequentially:
   [image]
3. Set up throttling builds, selecting "Throttle this project as part of one or more categories", "Multi-Project Throttle Category"(qa-aut) and "Throttle Matrix configuration builds". You can leave in blank the rest of the values
   [image]
4. Make sure your node/master has enough executors available. In this case, the master will have available 4 executors
   [image]
5. Execute your multi-project job
   [image]
6. Instead of using 4 executors (all the availability), you will see it's using only 2 executors (2 threads) as specified in the category.

[image]